# Issue with app.yaml to deploy static website on App Engine, images won't display

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my web app on Google App Engine.
My project follows this structure

[image]

The `app.yaml` has this content:

```
runtime: nodejs14
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
```

But, when I execute `gcloud app deploy --project=MY PROJECT`, and open my site, it looks like this:

[image]

I assume there is an error in the app.yaml file, but I don't understand what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your second URL handler to:

```
- url: /(.*\.(svg|png))$
  static_files: www/images/\1
  upload: www/images/.*\.(svg|png)$
```

Then reference your img src like this:

```
<img src="/test.png" alt="oops" width="104" height="142">
```

---

One thing to add, you can also use `static_dir` as your second URL handler instead. This way it's easier organize static files per directory. Change your app.yaml to:

```
runtime: nodejs14
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /static-img
  static_dir: www/images
```

In that example, what happens is that images located at `www/images` are mapped on URLs beginning at `/static-img`. You can use that URL to reference your img src in your HTML. For example:

```
<img src="/static-img/test.png" alt="oops" width="104" height="142">
```

Learn more at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_static_dir